# How to bypass download manager and download the files from web?

Tags: windows, download, website, download-manager

Now a days almost on all websites we see some kind of download managers which we need to download first. when we run that file then it manages the original file download which is a bit annoying for me. Is there anyway to bypass such download managers and download the original file directly in old kind of way?

Comment: Avoid Softonic :) and go for free (in the sense of free speech) or open source software: they always give the binary or the source code, without annoying installers.

Comment: Try to download from softpedia and brothersoft they are good sites. Also there are many sites available to download the software without download the download manager of the sites.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. If there really isn't a "manually download" link on the page (frequently there is, it's just obscured/not obvious on many websites that use download managers), then there's probably not an easy way to bypass the manager program.

Sometimes, but not often, [using an obscure browser](http://dottech.org/tipsntricks/20355/quick-tip-use-alternative-not-so-popular-browsers-to-bypass-annoying-download-managers/) will trigger manual downloads since the manager apps can't get hooks to install. Don't bet on this, though.

Websites that use download managers often use them because advertisements or other spam are distributed with the manager app. The site owners will get money for exposing you to those ads/spam, so it would be against their interests to provide you with an obvious, easy-to-use manual link that bypasses it. This is evil and annoying, but an unfortunate cost of doing business with some sites.

Some sites don't do this: Dell, for example, allows manual download, but also provides a download manager which can come in handy when downloading dozens or hundreds of driver files.

A good rule of thumb is: if there isn't an easy-to-see "manually download" link/button, try to find a different site that provides the file you're after.